# Most common subset of size k

Tags: algorithm, combinatorics

Suppose you have a list of subsets `S1,...,Sn` of the integer range `R={1,2,...,N}`, and an integer `k`. Is there an efficient way to find a subset `C` of `R` of size `k` such that `C` is a subset of a maximal number of the `Si`?

As an example, let `R={1,2,3,4}` and `k=2`

```
S1={1,2,3}
S2={1,2,3}
S3={1,2,4}
S4={1,3,4}
```

Then I want to return either `C={1,2}` or `C={1,3}` (doesn't matter which).

Comment: This looks a lot like frequent subset mining/basket mining. Check out the [apriori algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apriori_algorithm).

Comment: @larsmans Yes, I am aware of these algorithms, but they are too general for my purpose; in some sense I only want a *most* frequent subset, not all frequent ones (there are way too many).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem is NP-Hard. Consider the bipartite graph with the left nodes being your sets and the right nodes being the integers `{1, ..., N}`, with an edge between two nodes if the set contains the integer. Then, finding a common subset of size `k`, which is a subset of a maximal number of the `Si`, is equivalent to finding a complete bipartite subgraph `K(i, k)` with maximal number of edges `i*k`. If you could do this in polynomial time, then, you could find the complete bipartite subgraph `K(i, j)` with maximal number of edges `i*j` in polynomial time, by trying for each fixed `k`. But this problem in NP-Complete ([Complete bipartite graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_bipartite_graph)).

So, unless P=NP, your problem does not have a polynomial time algorithm.

Comment: Finding the maximal set which is a subset of **all** the given sets is simply an intersection on all of those subsets, it can be done in polynomial time.

Comment: Sure, but this is not equivalent with the problem asked.

Comment: Interesting, good observation. Are you familiar with any pseudo-polynomial/randomized approaches for related problems?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I can't even think of good references on that subject.

Comment: @Edouard: Actually, rethinking about your comment, I am not really looking to finding a complete bipartite subgraph with maximal number of *edges* `i*j`, but rather maximal number of *nodes* `i` on the left side.

Comment: Sure. But for fixed `j` (which is equal to `k` in your problem), this is equivalent. Then, if you can do it for each (fixed) `j` in polynomial time, you can find a complete bipartite subgraph with maximal number of edges `i*j` by searching for each fixed `j` and keeping the best.

Comment: But as far as I understand, you can't fix `j`; the problem you refer to is to find a complete bipartite subgraph with maximal number of edges, right? (A reference to the result may help actually :) Wikipedia doesn't have a corresponding link)

Comment: Yes, I refer to the problem of finding a complete bipartite subgraph with maximal number of edges, as being NP-Complete. The "trick" to fix `j` is to solve the  (sub)problem for each value of `j`. Then, solving the NP-Complete problem is equivalent to solving `N` (sub)problems (one for each value of `j`). If you can solve each (sub)problem in polynomial time, solving `N` problems also has a polynomial time complexity.

Comment: Ok I got mixed up, I agree with you again :) Thanks for the patient explanation. Would you happen to have the reference to that result?

Comment: [The maximum edge biclique problem is NP-complete](http://arno.uvt.nl/show.cgi?fid=99408), by R. Peeters.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming I understand your question I believe this is straightforward for fairly small sets.

I will use *Mathematica* code for illustration, but the concept is universal.

I generate `10` random subsets of length `4`, from the set {1 .. 8}:

```
ss = Subsets[Range@8, {4}] ~RandomSample~ 10
```

> ```
> {{1, 3, 4, 6}, {2, 6, 7, 8}, {3, 5, 6, 7}, {2, 4, 6, 7}, {1, 4, 5, 8},
>  {2, 4, 6, 8}, {1, 2, 3, 8}, {1, 6, 7, 8}, {1, 2, 4, 7}, {1, 2, 5, 7}}
> ```

I convert these to a binary array of the presence of each number in each subset:

```
a = Normal@SparseArray[Join @@ MapIndexed[Tuples[{##}] &, ss] -> 1];

Grid[a]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

That is ten columns for ten subsets, and eight rows for elements {1 .. 8}.

Now generate all possible target subsets (size `3`):

```
keys = Subsets[Union @@ ss, {3}];
```

Take a "key" and extract those rows from the array and do a BitAnd operation (return `1` iff all columns equal `1`), then count the number of ones.  For example, for key `{1, 6, 8}` we have:

```
a[[{1, 6, 8}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

After BitAnd:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Do this for each key:

```
counts = Tr[BitAnd @@ a[[#]]] & /@ keys;
```

Then find the position(s) of the maximum element of that list, and extract the corresponding parts of `keys`:

```
keys ~Extract~ Position[counts, Max@counts]
```

> ```
> {{1, 2, 7}, {2, 4, 6}, {2, 4, 7}, {2, 6, 7}, {2, 6, 8}, {6, 7, 8}}
> ```

With adequate memory this process works quickly for a larger set.  Starting with 50,000 randomly selected subsets of length `7` from {1 .. 30}:

```
ss = Subsets[Range@30, {7}] ~RandomSample~ 50000;
```

The maximum sub-subsets of length `4` are calculated in about nine seconds:

```
AbsoluteTiming[
  a = Normal@SparseArray[Join @@ MapIndexed[Tuples[{##}] &, ss] -> 1];
  keys = Subsets[Union @@ ss, {4}];
  counts = Tr[BitAnd @@ a[[#]]] & /@ keys;
  keys~Extract~Position[counts, Max@counts]
]
```

> ```
>  {8.8205045, {{2, 3, 4, 20},
>               {7, 10, 15, 18},
>               {7, 13, 16, 26},
>               {11, 21, 26, 28}}}
> ```

I should add that *Mathematica* is a high level language and these operations are on generic objects, therefore if this is done truly at the binary level this should be much faster, and more memory efficient.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. In my case, I really want to avoid generating all possible subsets of size `k` since for example I have an instance with `N=1000` and `k=100`, which means I would have to generate about 10^140 subsets.

Comment: @mitchus are your subsets S1..Sn *all possible* subsets of that size, or an arbitrary group of subsets?

Comment: they are an arbitrary group, possibly with several repeating instances (in my example S1 and S2 are the same).

Comment: @mitchus that's what I was afraid of.  I am certainly not an expert on such things but I suspect that this is simply not computable given your set size.  I would try to approach the problem differently or settle for a "good" but not optimum result via heuristics.

Answer (score 1):

I hope I don't misunderstand the problem... Here a solution in SWI-Prolog

```
:- module(subsets, [solve/0]).
:- [library(pairs),
    library(aggregate)].

solve :-
    problem(R, K, Subsets),
    once(subset_of_maximal_number(R, K, Subsets, Subset)),
    writeln(Subset).

problem(4, 2,
[[1,2,3], [1,2,3], [1,2,4], [1,3,4]]).

problem(8, 3,
[[1, 3, 4, 6], [2, 6, 7, 8], [3, 5, 6, 7], [2, 4, 6, 7], [1, 4, 5, 8],
 [2, 4, 6, 8], [1, 2, 3, 8], [1, 6, 7, 8], [1, 2, 4, 7], [1, 2, 5, 7]]).

subset_of_maximal_number(R, K, Subsets, Subset) :-
    flatten(Subsets, Numbers),
    findall(Num-Count,
        (   between(1, R, Num),
            aggregate_all(count, member(Num, Numbers), Count)
        ), NumToCount),
    transpose_pairs(NumToCount, CountToNumSortedR),
    reverse(CountToNumSortedR, CountToNumSorted),
    length(Subset, K), % list of free vars
    prefix(SolutionsK, CountToNumSorted),
    pairs_values(SolutionsK, Subset).
```

test output:

```
?- solve.
[1,3]
true ;
[7,6,2]
true.
```

**edit:** I think that the above solution is wrong, in the sense that what's returned could not be a subset of any of the input: here (a commented) solution without this problem:

```
:- module(subsets, [solve/0]).
:- [library(pairs),
    library(aggregate),
    library(ordsets)].

solve :-
    problem(R, K, Subsets),
    once(subset_of_maximal_number(R, K, Subsets, Subset)),
    writeln(Subset).

problem(4, 2,
[[1,2,3], [1,2,3], [1,2,4], [1,3,4]]).

problem(8, 3,
[[1, 3, 4, 6], [2, 6, 7, 8], [3, 5, 6, 7], [2, 4, 6, 7], [1, 4, 5, 8],
 [2, 4, 6, 8], [1, 2, 3, 8], [1, 6, 7, 8], [1, 2, 4, 7], [1, 2, 5, 7]]).

subset_of_maximal_number(R, K, Subsets, Subset) :-
    flatten(Subsets, Numbers),
    findall(Num-Count,
        (   between(1, R, Num),
            aggregate_all(count, member(Num, Numbers), Count)
        ), NumToCount),

    % actually sort by ascending # of occurrences
    transpose_pairs(NumToCount, CountToNumSorted),
    pairs_values(CountToNumSorted, PreferredRev),

    % we need higher values first
    reverse(PreferredRev, Preferred),

    % empty slots to fill, preferred first
    length(SubsetP, K),
    select_k(Preferred, SubsetP),

    % verify our selection it's an actual subset of any of subsets
    sort(SubsetP, Subset),
    once((member(S, Subsets), ord_subtract(Subset, S, []))).

select_k(_Subset, []).
select_k(Subset, [E|R]) :-
    select(E, Subset, WithoutE),
    select_k(WithoutE, R).
```

test:

```
?- solve.
[1,3]
true ;
[2,6,7]
true.
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am not really familiar with Prolog, so I have trouble figuring out your code. I know that Prolog is essentially declarative, so here do you essentially just specify the problem and hope the engine finds a smart way to solve it, or are you actually guiding the search in some way?

Comment: Sets are represented as ordered lists. Most builtins used here are deterministic, i.e. have just a solution. The algorithm it's rather elementary, the search capability of Prolog is used just in **select_k**, that is similar to a permutation generator. **select** take an element from the list. Being sorted, elements are selected in decreasing frequency. Sort is needed to use make  use of **ord_subtract**.